# How to get transaction effect in React.js Project?

Tags: reactjs, transition, fadeout, effect, pjax

I want a page transaction effect like :
old page fade out and new page fade in.
I am not sure how to do it and I need your help.
If you have experiences on this field, please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are using react-router: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/animated-transitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little complicated for begineers , you will need fadeInPage and fadeOutPage class , and you need to build a custom prop , to make delay before transition and maintain a context state to change to toggle  fadeInPage and fadeOutPage class , make sure to maintain the seconds in React component and css same

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Route, Switch, useHistory, useLocation, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Apple from "./Apple";
import { useState, useEffect, createContext, useReducer } from "react";
export const FadeContext = createContext();

const initialState = {
  fade: "fadeInPage"
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FADEIN":
      return {
        ...state,
        fade: "fadeInPage"
      };
    case "FADEOUT":
      return {
        ...state,
        fade: "fadeOutPage"
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export const DelayLink = (props) => {
  const { delay, onDelayStart, onDelayEnd, replace, to, ...rest } = props;
  let timeout = null;
  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      }
    };
  }, [timeout]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    // if trying to navigate to current page stop everything
    if (location?.pathname === to) return;

    onDelayStart(e, to);
    if (e.defaultPrevented) {
      return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      if (replace) {
        history.replace(to);
      } else {
        history.push(to);
      }
      onDelayEnd(e, to);
    }, delay);
  };

  return <Link {...rest} to={to} onClick={handleClick} />;
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const [fade, setFade] = useState(false);

  return (
    <FadeContext.Provider
      value={{
        state,
        dispatch
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <span style={{ zIndex: "9999" }}>
          <DelayLink
            to={"/home"}
            replace={true}
            delay={2000}
            onDelayStart={() => {
              dispatch({ type: "FADEOUT" });
            }}
            onDelayEnd={() => {
              dispatch({ type: "FADEIN" });
            }}
            style={{ cursor: "pointer", textDecoration: "underline" }}
          >
            Home
          </DelayLink>
          <br />
          <DelayLink
            to={"/apple"}
            replace={false}
            delay={2000}
            onDelayStart={() => {
              dispatch({ type: "FADEOUT" });
            }}
            onDelayEnd={() => {
              dispatch({ type: "FADEIN" });
            }}
            style={{ cursor: "pointer", textDecoration: "underline" }}
          >
            Apple
          </DelayLink>
        </span>

        <Switch>
          <Route path={"/home"} exact fade={fade}>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path={"/apple"} fade={fade}>
            <Apple />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </FadeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.fadeInPage {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

.fadeOutPage {
  -webkit-animation: fadeout 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadeout 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadeout 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadeout 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadeout 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

There is a lot of code , so ref this repo for good understanding

[image: Edit proud-sound-0sjx2]

Comment: Thanks but this code is for added page.  But i want to fade out the remove page.

Comment: I have added code for both FadeIn and FadeOut , please upvote and accept the anwer if you find this useful